# Experimental tests of Cluster Decmposition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, astrophysics, specific-reference, experimental-physics

How tight are experimental and astrophysical tests on whether Cluster Decomposition is satisfied at various space-like separations?

Is there a review paper or a standard reference on the question?

I note that Cluster Decomposition may be related to the existence of a unique vacuum state and to [spontaneous symmetry breaking](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29311/what-is-spontaneous-symmetry-breaking-in-quantum-systems/29337#29337).