# Examples of symmetric field collapse to produce asymmetry

Tags: symmetry, symmetry-breaking, wavefunction-collapse

It would really help me with an idea I have if I could see how something such as a symmetric field could collapse to something asymmetric.  I know that if $x$ occures before $y$ is symmetric, then $y$ occurs before $x$, which doesn't make sense if we take time to be asymmetric (only flowing in one direction). Is there a relationship between energy in the universe being symmetric, and the production of anti-matter asymmetric?

I am mostly interested in the collapse of the wavefunction, and a search to find if this collapse is asymmetric I am left with the thought that I might have to specify what the symmetry/asymmetry would be in respect to, that being said, is there some sort of "field" whether physical or purely abstract which is symmetric and if a "disturbance" (observation?) happens, there is a collapse to an asymmetric field such as the collapse of the wavefunction? Maybe I have it all wrong?

- Digging deeper, what I am looking for examples of, especially of quantum systems is that of "symmetry breaking". I also found the answered question concerning spontaneous symmetry breaking in Quantum mechanics here: [spontaneous symmetry breaking in Quantum Systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29311/what-is-spontaneous-symmetry-breaking-in-quantum-systems), and while I have some background in physics and pure math, I hope to get a much more canonical answer so as to understand more the foundations. \

Comment: Quoting part of the accepted answer concerning the link above: 

"The spontaneous symmetry breaking in the ground state of a quantum system can be defined as the long range entanglement between any two far-separated points in this system, in any ground state that preserves the global symmetries of the system."

I am curious to know why the system goes from symmetry to asymmetry. I can understand the mutual information: $I_{12}=S_1+S_2-S_{12}$ but how does this work together with the breaking of symmetry?

Comment: Regarding the text in the bounty description, gravitational effects are not necessarily symmetric. Many solutions to the Einstein field equations possess a symmetry, e.g. $SO(3)$. However these ideal solutions rarely exist in Nature; perturbations will likely remove e.g. a spherical symmetry.

Comment: Also, many exact solutions to Einstein's equations that have no symmetries are known.